# Combining nested arrays based on ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, reduce, frequency

I have multiple objects of which I would like to concatenate their nested arrays based on an ID. For example:

```
data = [
        {roomId: 1,
         nights: [ "2022-05-06",
                   "2022-05-07"
                 ] 
        },

        {roomId: 2,
         nights: [ "2022-05-06",
                   "2022-05-07",
                   "2022-05-08"
                 ] 
        },

        {roomId: 1,
         nights: [ "2022-05-10",
                   "2022-05-11",
                   "2022-05-07",
                 ] 
        },

        {roomId: 2,
         nights: [ "2022-05-12",
                   "2022-05-13",
                   "2022-05-14"
                 ] 
         }
]
```

For each roomId I would like to create one nights array with all the dates (including duplicates). Ideally I would have a count for the frequency of each night in that array as well.

Desired Output

```
newObject = [
        {roomId: 1,
         nights: [ {date:"2022-05-06", count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-07", count:2}
                   {date:"2022-05-10", count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-11", count:1}
                 ] 
        },

        {roomId: 2,
         nights: [ {date:"2022-05-06",count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-07",count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-08",count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-12",count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-13",count:1}
                   {date:"2022-05-14",count:1}
                 ] 
        },
]
```

I have tried a couple map and reduce functions but have not been able to come up with anything that is producing the results I'm looking for. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are supposed to show what you tried, for 'helping hands', not asking for free code. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. did you also read this site quideline https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: data.sort((a, b) => a.roomId - b.roomId).reduce((prev, current) => {
console.log(prev, current)
        return !!prev && Array.isArray(prev) ?
          prev[prev.length - 1].roomId === current.roomId ?
            prev.map((item, index) => {return index === prev.length - 1 ? {...item, nights: [...item.nights, ...current.nights]} : item}) :
            [...prev, current] :
          prev.roomId === current.roomId ?
            [{...prev, nights: [...prev.nights, ...current.nights]}]:
            [prev, current]
    })

this work try a method to optimize the function